# Magento 2 moving cart page main title to columns section is not working

Tags: magento2, layout-update, page-title

I've to move page title **"Shopping Cart"** into columns container/div.

So to do so in `checkout_cart_index.xml` file I've made changes.

**app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns container" />
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="columns" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

But after flushing cache and all still title not moved.

Where Am I making mistake??

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this in LUMA Theme.

\vendor\magento\theme-frontend luma\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml
After the `<body>` tag, i placed it

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="columns"  before="-"/>
```

> Once i remove the cache and opens firebug, the page title was moved to
>   Columns section.

Comment: Not working in Magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is useful for you,

Add this code:

**app\design\frontend\mypackage\mytheme\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
        <update handle="checkout_shipping_price_renderer"/>
        <body>

        <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-" />

        </body>
    </page>
```

After remove cache then check it.